# orthogonal projections and equivalent projections in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumanna algebra.

Does there exist relationship between equivalent projections in $M$ and orthogonal projections in $M$?

If $p$ and $q$ are equivalent non-trivial projections, is it possible that $pq=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't really any relationships in a general von Neumann algebra. Here are some type I examples: take $M = M_2$, the algebra of 2x2 matrices. The projections
$$ 1 \oplus 0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
are equivalent (two projections in $M_2$ are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank) and orthogonal. But
$$ 1 \oplus 0 \text{ and } \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
are equivalent and not orthogonal.

If we go to $M_3$, the 3x3 matrices, its easy to find two projections which are orthogonal and not equivalent (just take the projection onto a plane and the projection onto the normal).

Comment: Even in $M_1$ (i.e. $\mathbb C$) there is the trivial example $p=1$ and $q=0$, which are orthogonal and not equivalent.

Comment: What about the type $III$ factors. I know the fact that any two projections in type $III$ factors are equivalent. Do there exist two non -orthogonal projections?

Comment: well I guess a trivial counter-example is take $q$ to be any non-trivial projection and $p = 1$ to be the unit. They're not orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks, but I wonder whether there exist non-trivial examples. I mean that $p\neq 1, q\neq 1$.

Comment: @mathbeginner Maybe use a dense subalgebra of the Powers' factors $\mathcal{R}_\lambda$ (an infinite-tensor product of M_2 with distinguished states) which is the unique type III$_\lambda$ hyperfinite factor (if $0 < \lambda < 1$). Doing it this way gets rid of any cross-product stuff that often comes up in the type III setting. I think you should be able to get something here.